# Cannot find module './*.env' node js

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, node-modules

when i try run npm run start o node server.js i get this error by require('./.env'), before run 
node server.js i run npm prune && npm install, i'm begginer with node js

```
module.js:478
throw err;


Error: Cannot find module './*.env'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\luis.a.dominguez\Desktop\inovation\code\app-endpoints-service\server.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

Comment: Check your `server.js` file is there any line with `'./*.env'`. then update your `server.js` code in question

Comment: hi, can we see your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With module js (.mjs) you do:

Install dotenv module. Yarn: `yarn dotenv` or Npm: `npm i dotenv`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
# all imports...
dotenv.config()
```

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed this happening several times for me when I used ngx-rocket to scaffold a new project. For some reason it seemed to miss part of the script.

Anyways it was easily fixed by running this command at the same root level as your app:

npm run env

Then build your app and run it, that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) it is easy to use and it can help you get the `.env` file with all the variables that are inside. It can be something like:

/yourfile.env

```
NAME=YOUR_NAME
```

/index.js

```
require('dotenv').config({path: 'yourfile.env'}
console.log(process.env.NAME) //YOUR_NAME
```